# pip uninstall: "No files were found to uninstall."

Tags: python-3.x, pip, uninstallation, python-wheel

I have created a python module, call it 'foo_bar'.

I can **install** it and I can **upgrade** it, but I **cannot uninstall** it.

I build my module using **bdist_wheel**:

```
$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

And I install and upgrade it as follows:

```
$ python3 -m pip --timeout 60 install --upgrade dist/foo_bar-1.4.3-py3-none-any.whl
```

It is listed within Python 3.4 framework directory:

```
ls -al /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
drwxr-xr-x   12 samwise  admin     408 Jun 21 02:50 foo_bar
drwxr-xr-x    9 samwise  admin     306 Jun 21 02:50 foo_bar-1.4.3.dist-info
```

And it listed within pip freeze:

```
$ python3 -m pip freeze
foo-bar==1.4.3
```

However, if I try to perform pip uninstall, it cannot find it's files

```
$ python3 -m pip uninstall foo-bar
Can't uninstall 'foo-bar'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Did I do something wrong within my setup.py for it not to be able to find my modules files during uninstall?

Version info is as follows:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.4
$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

Comment: Did you try to delete it in your library file? Maybe it works

Comment: Yes, I could perform a hard delete using `rm -fR`, but that seems not a proper way of performing an `uninstall`. I am planning in making the module public on pypi, and if it cannot be uninstalled properly then this would not be favorable to the python community.

Comment: @jeff00seattle did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: For me, using `sudo` solved the problem

Comment: I wonder whether the same issue arises when using a letters-only name. I was always told that package names with hyphens were highly discouraged, especially to avoid confusion or usage issues.

Answer (score 35):

I had the same issue. Using `verbose` helped me to find out a bit more the reason:

```
$ pip3 uninstall --verbose my-homemade-package
Not sure how to uninstall: my-homemade-package e48e635 - Check: /home/olivier/my-homemade-package
Can't uninstall 'my-homemade-package'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Removing everything that was 'my-homemade-package' related in `/usr/local/python2.x` and `/usr/local/python3.x` did not help.

I did a `pip3 show my-homemade-package` and got the location of the installed package on my computer:

```
$ pip3 show my-homemade-package
Name: my-homemade-package
Version: e48e635
Summary: My Home Made package
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Proprietary
Location: /home/olivier/my-homemade-package
Requires: pyOpenSSL, pyasn1, protobuf
```

Removing `/home/olivier/my-homemade-package` sorted it out the issue (ie: the package was not listed).

Comment: I managed to overwrite the installed package by installing the without uninstalling:

`$  pip3 install my-homemade-package --force`

Comment: `rm -r build dist __pycache__ *.egg* .egg*`

Answer (score 16):

So I was having a similar issue to OP. I could install my package with `pip install dist/mypackage.tar.gz`. Installation would work fine, but at the end it would show `Can't uninstall 'mypackage'. No files were found to uninstall.`, and indeed `pip uninstall mypackage` wouldn't work later on.

It sounds silly but what worked for me was to *change working directory*: once I left `mypackage/` directory, `pip uninstall mypackage` worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59996027/3149277 this answer is to the point.

Comment: My issue had the same cause.  The reason may be that pip tries to uninstall `mypackage` in the current (dev) directory instead of the package elsewhere in the system.

Answer (score 13):

This is an old post, but it was top result in Google. The above answers are correct, however, in my case there was still line /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth that I had to remove after also removing the egg files.

Comment: Thanks! I was so confused how pip knew that my package existed despite manually deleting the package's egg link in the site-packages folder. Deleting the entry in the pth file fully resolved it for me.

Comment: The easy-install.pth line is what I was missing after manually removing the egg/egg-link cruft. Cheers!

Comment: As a side note, there might be a line in *any* .pth file in site-packages which makes the package seen with `pip list` and importable by python.

Answer (score 8):

I had such issue when I renamed my module in `setup.py`.

Old `old_name.egg-info` directory still existed in `my_module` directory. So, when I installed module with `pip install -e .` pip created a line in `python3.8/site-packages/easy-install.pth` pointing to module directory. After that module was listed by `pip list` with both names: `new-name` and `old-name`. And when I tried to remove old module with `pip remove old-name` pip showed error:

```
Found existing installation: old-name 0.3.0
Can't uninstall 'old-name'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

The solution was to remove directory `old_name.egg-info` from module directory. After that `pip list` shows only `new-name`.

Probably it is not direct answer to original post but one of the solutions for issue in topic-name.

Comment: Hi, where is this old_name.egg-info is supposed to be? in which directory?

Comment: @HedwinBonnavaud in the `my_module` directory, where `setup.py` is located.

Answer (score -2):

Issue: User cannot uninstall a python package installed via pip:

```
pip uninstall youtube-dl
Found existing installation: youtube-dl 2021.12.17
Not uninstalling youtube-dl at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'youtube-dl'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Reason: PEBKAC.

Well, a simple

```
apt purge youtube-dl
```

did the trick. There had been a system package "youtube-dl" installed, with said version:

```
dpkg -l youtube-dl
ii  youtube-dl     2021.12.17-1~nd110+1
```

At the same time users used to install packages locally using pip. Both packages of the same version (2021.12.17). And both ways (apt and pip) referred to the packages by the same name. Turned out, this tends to confuse users..

Next level: Have a package installed three ways: apt, pip --system and plain pip as user. Maybe pip as root (locally) FWIW, too.