# Can't uninstall 'spam'. No files were found to uninstall

Tags: python, pip

I installed a local package, `spam`, using `python3 -m pip install --user .`. It installed correctly; it is visible in the `site-packages` folder and can be `import`ed.

However, if I try to uninstall my package, I get the following:

```sh
$ python3 -m pip uninstall --verbose spam
Not sure how to uninstall: spam 0.0.1 - Check: /Users/me/spam
Can't uninstall 'spam'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Why can't I uninstall my package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that I was in the source directory with a folder named `spam`. The uninstall completes successfully when I run it from a different directory:

```
$ pwd
/Users/me/spam

$ ls
README.md  setup.cfg  setup.py  test  tox.ini  spam

$ cd \tmp && python3 -m pip uninstall spam
# successfully uninstalls...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reynoldsnlp's answer, I wanted to share another solution that solved my simiar issue.

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/59996027/18280620 it turned out that it was in my easy install path:

```
.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/easy-install.pth
```